# Postfix - Refusing to send emails to some domains

Tags: postfix

For example

```
/\.host$/ REJECT We reject all .host domains!
/\.pw$/ REJECT We reject all .pw domains!
```

In this way, I prevent the receiving of e-mails from the domain names I want. No problem here.

I don't want emails to be sent to the domain names that I have determined that I am trying to do. Example;

```
.com.br
.it
.host
```

like this. Is there a way to do this? I repeat, what I want to do is block the outgoing.

Comment: If restricting by sender is no problem, why would restricting by recipient be? Just add the lookup rule you added with `check_sender_access` also with `check_recipient_access`..

Comment: By the way, a few Italians might chose strong words when judging the culinary crimes of the world, but refusing to exchange mail with anyone in the entire `.it` TLD is still slightly overkill. You may find that some existing, more fine-grained dynamic list (keyword: `DNSRBL`) is better suited for whatever comms barrier you are about to setup.

Answer (score 0):

In principle what you are asking for is a simple [transport maps](https://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html). To block a delivery you can set transport to "error", and provide an additional error message to the sender:

```
.example.com     error:mail for *.example.com is not deliverable
```

Put this (and similar) lines into the text file file, for example, `/etc/postfix/my_transport_maps`, one rule per line.

After creation and each time you update the file, you need to "compile" it by running `postmap /etc/postfix/my_transport_maps`. Then you connect it into the system by adding into `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/my_transport_maps
```

and reloading Postfix.

Comment: peki örneğin .it .hold .com.br sadece uzantı olarak yasaklama nasıl yapılabilir?

Comment: Probably I'd be able to answer if you ask it in english.

Comment: well, for example, how can .it .hold .com.br be banned only as an extension?

Comment: I can't understand this either. What means "as an extension"?